# Convert Query result to strings from Unicode

Tags: python, django

I'm running a script every half hour or so comparing states of jobs in the Job table if i query the database i get back results in this format:

```
(u'production_assignment', u'22', datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 17, 12, 13, 44,
839672, tzinfo=<UTC>))
```

Is there anyway to convert this back to the same data style that is recorded in the table?

EDIT - OUTPUT (Nowhere near finished need to work little snags out like this first)

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    # Show this when the user types help
    help = "My test command"

    # A command must define handle()
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        #Job_set = Job.objects.order_by('status').values('status').distinct() PriorityPoints__lte=50
        Job_set = Job.objects.filter(ref_number = 36175).values_list('status', 'serial_no', 'due_date')

        for jobs in Job_set:
            self.stdout.write(jobs)
```

Comment: You should show the code you are using and the output you want.

Comment: You need to serialize the job_set somehow.  Python doesn't know which format you need to ouput. The best way to go would be to create a function jobset_to_string which does the job.